# line integrals and partial derivatives statement (Green's theorem application)

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $P(x,y),Q(x,y)$ be $C^1$ functions of $\mathbb R^2$, prove that the following statements are equivalent:

(1) $P_x-Q_y=0$ and $P_y+Q_x=0$

(2) For every simple closed curve $C$, it is satisfied $$\int_C P(x,y)dx-Q(x,y)dy=0, \space \int_C Q(x,y)dx+P(x,y)dy=0$$

I could do (1) implies (2) applying Green's theorem. I have no idea how to show (2) $\implies$ (1), any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the complex valued function $f(x+iy):=P(x,y)+iQ(x,y)$.

**EDIT:**

For a multivariable calculus approach, observe that since

$$\oint_C P(x,y)dx-Q(x,y)dy=0 $$ for all closed curves $C$, the differential 1-form $\omega:=Pdx-Qdy$ is said to be exact. Moreover, since exact forms are closed, we find $P_y=-Q_x$. Repeating the same reasoning gives the other equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is an exercise from a multivariable calculus course where we aren't supposed to use tools from complex analysis, can you think of a hint/suggestion using things from multivariable calculus?

Comment: @user156441 edited.